# Wrapping a C++ class method in a try catch block with added functionality

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, try-catch, class-method

Coming from mostly interpreted and dynamically typed languages, I'm a little stuck on how to approach this problem in C++.

I have a class `Child` which inherits from `Parent` and adds some functionality. I would like class `Parent` to implement a function (perhaps `trycatch`) that would wrap a function from class `Child` in a try catch with some logic prefixed and suffixed, so that `Child` can call its own functions using this `trycatch`.

This was my first way of implementing it:

```
class Parent{
    public:
        void trycatch(*magicly take function as parameter f*){
            // do some logic perhaps saving some state.
            try{
                f(); // error prone function
            } catch (e){
                // restore some state
            }
            // do some stuff finally
        }
};
```

So that the child class could then do this:

```
class Child : public Parent{
    public:
        void foo(){
            trycatch(bar);
        }
        void bar(){
            // do error prone stuff
        }
};
```

This leaves me with the following questions:

1. How to implement this class method as an argument. I tried this `void (*f)()` and `void (*Parent::f)` but the compiler was not having it.
2. Is this a bad way of doing things in C++, are there other (better) ways?
3. Is this a bad use of polymorphism?

Comment: The argument to `trycatch()` would be `void (*Parent::f)()`.    Within the function, it would be called as `(*this.*f)()` or `(this->*f)()`  or (for another object of type `Parent`) `(object.*f)()`.    Bear in mind that, if the function passed is virtual that the most derived version would be called.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i needed.

Comment: @Peter When defining the function signature like this `void (*Parent::f)()`, the compiler complains with `Parameter declarator cannot be qualified`. Any ideas what is going on there?

Comment: I wrote too fast.  Change argument spec to `void (Parent::*f)()`   (not `void (*Parent::f)()`).   Call it by passing `&Parent::bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no comments on your design.

Here is how to make it work.

```
void trycatch(std::function<void()> f){
  // setup
  try{
    f();
  } catch( blah ) {
    // cleanup
  }
  // finish
}
```

at call site:

```
trycatch([&]{ someMethod(); });
```

and done.

Comment: Offcourse, i didn't yet consider lambdas!

Comment: `std::function` might be replaced by template (to avoid the overhead of `std::function`, but not explicit on expected callable).